# thread module question

Tags: python

so i have the code:

```
def Listen(filepath):
        def play(filepath):

            def play_music(music_file):
                """
                stream music with mixer.music module in blocking manner
                this will stream the sound from disk while playing
                """
                clock = pygame.time.Clock()

                pygame.mixer.music.load(music_file)


                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
                    # check if playback has finished
                    clock.tick(30)


            # pick a MP3 or MIDI music file you have ...
            # (if not in working folder, use full path)
            music_file = filepath
            #music_file = "ChancesAre.mid"

            # set up the mixer
            freq = 44100     # audio CD quality
            bitsize = -16    # unsigned 16 bit
            channels = 2     # 1 is mono, 2 is stereo
            buffer = 2048    # number of samples (experiment to get right sound)
            pygame.mixer.init(freq, bitsize, channels, buffer)

            # optional volume 0 to 1.0
            pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)


            play_music(music_file)
        thread.start_new_thread(play,(filepath))
```

and i get an error:

```
File "C:\Users\Desktop\WhaleTunes.py", line 59, in Listen
    thread.start_new_thread(play,(filepath))
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 2nd arg must be a tuple
```

Does anyone know why i get this error?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Read the TypeError message: "2nd arg must be a tuple." You have `(filepath)`. This is not a tuple. A tuple of one element should be written: `(filepath,)` to disambiguate.

Comment: Do you know why it has to be a tuple?

Comment: @salks: So there's no special case between functions that take zero args, one arg, or multiple args. You just always pass a tuple.

Comment: Because apparently the method/function `start_new_thread` demands it.

Comment: And I'd wager it demands it because of the reason FogleBird mentioned.

Comment: I should also mention that this is also the case had you use the stdlib way: `threading.Thread(target=play, args=(filepath,))`. It's a common idiom in Python.